# Insert primary key identity(id) into other table as foreign key

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables in SQL(InjuryScenario and ProductTypeDet)

```
CREATE TABLE InjuryScenario
(

InjuryScenario_id int identity(1,1),
InjuryScenario_name varchar(80),
InjuryDay int,
InjuryMonth int,
InjuryYear int,
InjuryDesc varchar(80),
InjuryComments varchar(50),
AlmostInjury int,
InjuryInSchool varchar(20),
ProductInjury varchar(20),
Cause_id int,
CauseType_id int,
CauseChar_id int,
Place_id int,
PlaceType_id int,
Username varchar(50),
InjuryDate_id int,
constraint pk_InjuryScenario_id primary key (InjuryScenario_id),
constraint fk_Cause_InjuryScenario foreign key(Cause_id) references Cause(Cause_id) on delete cascade,
constraint fk_CauseType_InjuryScenario foreign key(CauseType_id) references CauseType(CauseType_id) on delete no action,
constraint fk_Place_InjuryScenario foreign key(Place_id) references Place(Place_id) on delete cascade,
constraint fk_PlaceType_InjuryScenario foreign key(PlaceType_id) references PlaceType(PlaceType_id) on delete no action,
constraint fk_Users_InjuryScenario foreign key(Username) references Users(Username) on delete cascade,
constraint fk_InjuryDate_InjuryScenario foreign key(InjuryDate_id) references InjuryDate(InjuryDate_id) on delete cascade, 
)


CREATE TABLE ProductTypeDet
(
ProductCategory_id int,
ProductType_id int,
Product_name varchar(80),
Brand_name varchar(80),
Notes varchar(80),
Manufacturer_name varchar(80),
Launch_Date date,
ProdTypeDesc varchar(80), 
ProductInjury varchar(20),
Status_id int,
SafetyAct_id int,
InjuryScenario_id int foreign key references InjuryScenario(InjuryScenario_id),
constraint fk_ProductCategory_ProductTypeDet foreign key(ProductCategory_id) references ProductCategory(ProductCategory_id) on delete cascade,
constraint fk_ProductType_ProductTypeDet foreign key(ProductType_id) references ProductType(ProductType_id) on delete no action,
constraint fk_ProductStatus_ProductTypeDet foreign key(Status_id) references ProductStatus(Status_id) on delete cascade,
constraint fk_SafetyAct_ProductTypeDet foreign key(SafetyAct_id) references Product(SafetyAct_id) on delete no action
)
```

in VS i have Insert function that inserts data from the user to the tables.

i built SQL trigger-

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_InjuryScenario_ForInsert
ON InjuryScenario
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Id int
SELECT @Id = InjuryScenario_id from inserted

INSERT INTO ProductTypeDet(InjuryScenario_id)
values(@Id) 

END
```

i have a problem that in ProductTypeDet table two rows created- one from the trigger(just with the InjuryScenario_id and the other coloumns are null) and the other one from the Insert function in vs(coloumns filled from the user selections and the InjuryScenario_id is null).
how can i linked those 2 rows into one?

Answer (score 0):

You never write a trigger like that! Inserted and deleted tables may contain multiple row and you tried to set the value to a scalar variable. (incidentally you should unit test triggers with multiple record inserts/updates or deletes) Use a set based propcess.

```
INSERT INTO ProductTypeDet(InjuryScenario_id)
SELECT  InjuryScenario_id from inserted
```

Comment: I changed it like you said and still have in ProductTypeDet table 2 rows... :(

Comment: If you inserted two rows into the orginal table, you shoudlhave two rows inthe other table

Comment: Oh wait i see that your application is also inserting rows, you need to turn off the aplcaition or not havea trigger at all, WHich you do depedns on how many differnt sources with be inserting records into the database. If the application is the only place they will come from then leav it there and take out the trigger, if the table will be populated from outside teh aplication at times, then take the insert out of the application and leave the trigger in.

Comment: i have to do the insert function because i don't have another way to take the user's selections.. how can i take the InjuryScenario_id to the ProductTypeDet without the trigger?

Comment: So let me get this straight, you are inserting to one table andyou need the data fomr that insert to use in another insert? Use the output clause instead of trigger.